# Container width is incorrectly calculated when using inline-flex with force break hack

Tags: css, flexbox

**! Flex is a requirement as in my project these items need to be reordered at different breakpoints.**

My container's width needs to expand to the width of the content - I cannot set a fixed width, nor use full-width. For this reason I used `inline-flex`.

I am using the flex break hack to force wrap after a certain number of items.

The problem is that the containers width is set as if the force break isn't even there.

I have 2 items, break, then 4 items. The width of the container should be equal to 4 items, but is equal to all 6 leaving a whitespace gap of 2 items.

**Codepen: https://codepen.io/jakehills/pen/JjdoPJO**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="i i1">i1</div>
  <div class="i i2">i2</div>
  <div class="break"></div>
  <div class="i i3">i3</div>
  <div class="i i4">i4</div>
  <div class="i i5">i5</div>
  <div class="i i6">i6</div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 0px; 
  height: 0px; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

> Edit March 2020: No solution was found - I had to build this another way. If you find a fix please submit your solution and I will update this question for future searchers.

Answer (score 0):

Flex not necessary here. I'd recommend to do it with inline-block/float.

https://codepen.io/vovchisko/pen/jOPENab

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.break {
  clear: both;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
}

.i {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but unfortunately flex is required as in my project these items need to be reordered at different breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your style:

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.break {
    height: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
}



/* JUST FOR VISIBILITY, NOT IMPORTANT FOR FUNCTIONING */
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  border: solid 2px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 20px;
}

.i {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.i1 { background: #fce3b6;}
.i2 { background: #c4e378;}
.i3 { background: #c9eeff;}
.i4 { background: #feab4d;}
.i5 { background: #e5b4ad;}
.i6 { background: #519600;}
```